# Simplify nested loops containing external variables

Tags: php, simplify, divide-and-conquer

I'm trying to simplify a piece of PHP code looking like this :

```
public function gather($parameters, $infos)
{

    $gathered = [];
    $number = false;

    foreach ($infos as $info) {

        foreach ($parameters as  $parameter) {

            if (strlen($parameter['number'])) {
                $this->mark($parameter['number'], $info, $parameter, $gathered); // $gathered is passed by reference
                $number = true;
                continue;
            }

            if (strlen($parameter['default'])) {
                $this->mark($parameter['default'], $info, $parameter, $gathered); // $gathered is passed by reference
                continue;
            }

            if ($config['smth']) {
                doSomething(...);
            }
        }
    }

    if (number > 0) {
        doSomething(...);
    }

    return $gathered;
}
```

Here are the problems I have :

- These nested foreaches are really ugly and I'd love to the second one in the other function. But it uses variables that are created and used outside. I already used references with `$gathered` even if it's not really good.
- The conditions of all ifs are different and are using different variables, do you know any way to generalize a case like this?

I am ok to rewrite big parts of the functions, so I'd be happy to hear other design ideas too.

[EDIT] The mark functions add elements to $gathered with some conditions and transformations.

[EDIT] Added more details.

Comment: You might be better off going to [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Read their tour to see if your question fits thought.

Comment: Its hard to give a design idea without knowing the purpose of this code.

Comment: And `$this->mark$info, $parameter, $gathered);` is most certainly a syntax error.

Comment: Yes, thanks, its edited..

Comment: "These nested foreaches are really ugly" -> why? if you need to loop over all values of B for all values of A, that's totally fine, having it in "an other function" would be relevant only if you would need to call it from another place.. Also for "The conditions of all ifs are different", we can't help you generalize without knowing these conditions.

Comment: Because the code is really hard to understand at first glance. Also sonar consider this function has a very high cognitive complexity

Comment: To help people help you, you might want to add an *copy-able* and *executable* code example (even if it's *dumbed down*). Currently, if someone wanted to help you, that someone would need to create all this code's dependencies just to start refactoring it.